# How to Properly Use repaint(); in Java

Tags: java, swing, awt, paint, repaint

This is my first time using swing graphics so bear with me. My current goal is to have a texture change when I press one of the arrow keys (to change the direction of the image that I am using). In doing this, I have created a paint method and I want to call it using `repaint();` when I press an arrow key. I was also thinking of having a parameter to paint so that it change what it is painting depending on that.

Here is the code that I have currently:

```
 //startGame.java
//Version 1.0
//09/06/2016

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;


public class Main extends JFrame
{


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Display Mode");
    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    frame.setUndecorated(true);


    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

    frame.addKeyListener(new KeyInput());

}
private static class KeyInput implements KeyListener
{
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke)
    {
        if(ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
        if(ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
        {
            //repaint();


        }
        /*if(ke.getKeyCOde() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
        {



        } */
    }
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke)
    {}
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke)
    {}
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    super.paint(g);
    ImageIcon player = new ImageIcon("RealPlayersV2.png");
    image = player.getImage();

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.drawImage(image, 187, 245, this);


}

}
```

In my private static class Keylistener, etc. I want to call `repaint();` so that my paint method will be called. Unfortunately, `repaint();` cannot be called from a static method like my keylistener method. Is there any elegant solution to using `repaint();` on a keypress? Thanks!

Comment: So? Don't make your inner `KeyInput` class static, it's not like it will be reusable in other contexts - it's private anyway.

Comment: KeyInput has to be static as it is referenced in the main method, which is static.

Answer (score -1):

Your Main class extends `JFrame` so it is one and you should use it and not create a new `JFrame` like you did in your main method.
Then you should move the frame initialisation to the constructor which will allow you to make `KeyListener` NOT static. And when its not static you are allowed to call the `repaint` method.

```
public class Main extends JFrame{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Main();
    }
    public Main(){
        super("Display Mode");
        setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setUndecorated(true);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
        addKeyListener(new KeyInput());
   }
   private class KeyInput implements KeyListener{
         [...] repaint(); [...]
   }
   @Override
   public void paint(Graphics g){...}
}
```

Comment: (1-) Don't override paint() on a JFrame. Custom painting is done by overriding paintComponent() on a JPanel and then you add the panel to the frame.